# how can i get a date object that has only time

Tags: java, datetime

I have a field "startdate"  which is of type DATE.I want to get only time in this field and that too in "yyyy-mm-dd" format.I tried too many things but can't get only the time in a DATE type object .I have to store it in database.

Any helps???

Comment: _I want to get only time in this field and that too in "yyyy-mm-dd" format_ it's confusing. You want only time but you are saying in yyyy-mm-dd format. Can you please clarify?

Comment: hey its my mistake to write this "yyyy-mm-dd" format .

Answer (score 2):

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond
>   precision.

([Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) in the manual)

So a Date object represents a *specific* moment in time (i.e., including the date). You are trying to put into it a time of day, which is an infinite set of moments: one fore each day.

You will need to pick a specific day yourself. Pick any day you like, since  you don't need it anyway.

Or you can use the subclass [java.sql.Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) which always uses January 1, 1970 as the date part.

Comment: hey i guess you dint answer my problem.

Comment: @user1742141, your question is unclear what you are trying to achieve, so you aren't getting good answers.